# How to Structure Firebase Realtime DB read request: Order by Key's Child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have data stored in a firebase realtime database, in the following format.

```
users:
    -L5ZAb7r10_nqss7Ag:
        role: "user"
        email: "person@example.com"
        username: "King Arthur"
    -KL3Abnar7_nals8:
        role: "admin"
        email: "other@example.com"
        username: "Queen Ferdinand"
```

And in the `database.rules.json` I have:

```
"users":{
  ".indexOn":["email"],
  ".write": false,
  ".read": "auth != null"
},
```

On the front end I have a user giving their email, having been authenticated with Google OAuth, and I want to see if their email is a valid user, and if so return their role and username, otherwise throw an error. Right now I loop through the 'n' accounts and check each account's email. O(n) is obviously a really sucky runtime.

Not knowing what the user's key in the database is (the "-L5ZAb7r10_nqss7Ag" part), I want to be able to check for the given email in O(1) by searching the email in the indexed database. What I have in mind is something like the below. If this is posisble can someone point me to the riht documentation for the correct syntax?

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/`).getIndexedValue($key/person@example.com).once('value').then(function(snap){
    if(snap == null) console.log("error);
    else{
       user = snap.val();
       console.log(user[role]);
       console.log(user[username]);
    }
}
```

I know the above won't work, `.getIndexedValue()` isn't real. What would be the correct syntax for this functionality? Is there someway to look for a specific indexed value (the email) that sits below an arbitrary partent (the `-KL3Abnar7_nals8`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `orderByChild()` and `equalTo()`. Something like this:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('users')
  .orderByChild('email')
  .equalTo('person@example.com')
  .once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(snap) {
       user = snap.val();
       console.log(user[role]);
       console.log(user[username]);
      })
    }
}
```

To learn more about Firebase Database queries, see the [documentation on sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data). I'd also recommend checking some previous [questions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+check+if+user+exists).

Comment: Thanks for the help!